# Failed to install "Calendar for LibreOffice" in 12.04

Tags: python, libreoffice

[image: My LibreOffice Version]
[image: Extention Manager]
[image: First error]
[image: Second and last error]

If anyone know what these errors mean, please enlighten everyone, thanks!

Comment: Try using this command to start LibreOffice: `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/ ; libreoffice`

Comment: @DoR If you believe there's a good chance that will actually solve the problem, you might want to post it (or something like it) as an answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Braiam, please look at the pictures. its self explanatory.

Comment: No is not. I don't use LO, nor anything related to it, so you have to explain where you are and where you want to go.

Comment: @Braiam, it is. i dont think you can help. if you can read the words in the pictures then you can put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: I use LO but don't know what these errors mean either, they don't look like errors related to Ubuntu, looks more like an issue with the extension you are trying to install....hence making this either off topic or unclear what your asking.....BTW snark when replying to a comment requesting clarification to your question will make it **MUCH** less likely you will get *anyone* to help you.......

Comment: he had no idea i was installing an extension or that it was on ubuntu. he asked me "where are you", the top of the window would give that answer. he asked me "where you want to go", the mouse cursor over the enable button would give that answer. i just dont like trolls that ask you what you are trying to do when it is in the pictures/question.